# What to do with a few Character tags

Tags: discussion, tags

It was brought up in chat and now an active merge request to merge [character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character), [character-motivation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-motivation), [character-analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-analysis) all into the [character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) tag.

My personal opinion is to keep the [character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) tag, and merge [character-motivation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-motivation) and [character-analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-analysis) together, as they are extremely similar, motivation being a specific of analysis.

What do you think?

Comment: What is going to happen with these tags now? I mean this question not getting attention and nobody given the suggestion except us .

Answer (score 3):

At first when i realize that there are three tags about character , i thought we should keep the [character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) tag as the master tag and keep the [character-analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-analysis) and [character-motivation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-motivation) as its synonym. [character-motivation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-motivation) is already covered under [character-analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-analysis) and both of them are covered under [character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) tag. That's why i requested to merge them by tag synonym request and even mentioned it in chat too. Because keeping all three tag isolated is not a good idea because they overlap each other.

I didn't think that [character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) tag should be kept separate because its also covered the whole   scenario of character and its analysis. So [character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) should be a master tag and other too tags its synonym.

Comment: I think putting them all under [tag:character] is a good idea as well. Using it combined with [tag:analysis] will make it clear if its character analysis or just something general like identification.

Comment: @atticae +1, Leaving only `character` and thus making it orthogonal to `analysis` keeps the tags cleanly purposed while still providing a high expressiveness by using combinations of both. In the end rarely a single tag is enough to classify a question, and this is a good thing.

Answer (score -2):

I think we should delete [character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) and retain [character-motivation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-motivation) and [character-analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-analysis) as separate tags.

Comment: There are some question which suits to character tag only like identify this character like question. So deleting character tag is a bad choice i think.